# bind of jquery does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am experimenting with jQuery. I have a code like

```
//some buttons to edit a div's style (add/remove classes)
<button class="size" id="switcher-large"> Large Print </button>
<button class="size" id="switcher-default"> Default </button>
<button class="size" id="switcher-narrow"> Narrow Column </button>

//buttons to activate/deactivate the above buttons
<button class="hide" id="hide"> Hide it </button>
<button class="hide" id="active"> Activate it </button>


//when buttons clicked, add/remove classes to a div
$('#switcher-large').click(function(){$('#one').removeClass().addClass('large'); });    
$('#switcher-default').click(function(){$('#one').removeClass(); });
$('#switcher-narrow').click(function(){$('#one').removeClass().addClass('narrow'); });

//activate/deactivate the buttons with the "size" class
$('#hide').click(function(){ $('.size').unbind('click'); });
$('#active').click(function(){$('.size').bind('click')});
```

Deactivating the buttons works fine. Activating them back again does not work. What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: bind is deprecated use ``on``

Comment: Neither `bind()` nor `on()` can magically deduce the handler you want to register if you do not pass it.

Comment: @Ehsan, also, it's been quite some time I did not have to point this out, but `bind()` *is not deprecated*.

Comment: Instead of binding/unbinding, you can just add a class to .size and in your click handler, check to see if that class exist or not to determine if you should or should not do something. You can always change the cursor in css to make it look like it is unclickable

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Ok, so needs a second argument. Something like `bind('click', click)` I guess? This does not work. And the documentation page shows ways to bind custom functions. But how can I bind a simple event like click, mouseover etc? Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to persist your use of `bind()` and `unbind()`, you need to store a reference to the event handlers you're binding/ unbinding. Here's an example for the `switcher-large` button.

```
//when buttons clicked, add/remove classes to a div
function switcherLargeHandler(){ $('#one').removeClass().addClass('large'); }

// Bind it by default
$('#switcher-large').click(switcherLargeHandler);  

$('#hide').click(function(){ $('#switcher-large').unbind('click', switcherLargeHandler); });
$('#active').click(function(){$('#switcher-large').bind('click', switcherLargeHandler)});
```

Note that:

```
$('#switcher-large').click(function () { /* Do something */ });
```

... is exactly the same as:

```
$('#switcher-large').bind('click', function () { /* Do something */ });
```

... which is exactly the same as:

```
$('#switcher-large').on('click', function () { /* Do something */ });
```

---

FWIW, `unbind()` without a second parameter will remove *all* `click` event handlers bound to an element; which is quite rude if you're in a shared enviroment, as you can potentially remove *other* event handlers you didn't know about.

Comment: As I suspected I cannot use `bind/unbind` for the whole class, at least not in this particular scenario. Also its a pitty that jquery cannot go like `bind('click', click)`, it would be so much faster/simpler. Anyway, thanks for your time mate.

Comment: @stevin: I'm not sure what you expect `click` to be as the second argument in your example?

Comment: User's action as the second argument in `bind`. The one I "deactivate" using `unbind`.

Answer (score 2):

`$('.size').bind('click')` is not valid. `bind()` needs to know *which* functions to bind as the handler.

There are 1,000,000 ways to do this, but you might find it easier to simply disable the buttons. This prevents the `click` handlers firing;

```
$('#hide').click(function(){ $('.size').prop('disabled', true); });
$('#active').click(function(){ $('.size').prop('disabled', false); });
```

Comment: Interesting. Thanks. But I want to use just `bind/unbind`, just because I am experimenting with jquery and want to see how those commands work.

Comment: @slevin: I've added another answer (since it's so different) to show how you'd use bind/ unbind. Note how verbose it'd get for all 3 buttons. You need to remember which event handlers need to be bound to each button.